# variable only defined when declared local

Tags: javascript

so i have a `onclick()` button linking to a function which is supposed to change the `display` attribute to none and back kind of like a modal, 
here is the function:

```
function setcart() {
  cart.style.display = "block";
  }
```

and here is the variable:

```
var cart = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-wrapper') [0];
```

when i declare the variable within the function everything works, problem is that i wanna be able to use the variable for another function so i set it outside the function and this is what i get in the browser console,

```
cart.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: The initialization is probably happening before the DOM is constructed, so at the time the code runs there are no matching elements.

Comment: i import the function at the end of the document, as far as i know this should prevent something like this

Comment: Well without seeing your code it's impossible to say *why* there are no matching elements, but that's clearly what's happening.

Comment: At what level is the `var cart = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-wrapper') [0];`? Is it inside a function? You should then have a `var chart;` at window level and a `cart = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-wrapper') [0];` inside the function.

Comment: There is not much more to my code then that

Comment: The variable is declared on the first line of the file, not inside any function

Comment: You should follow the answer by Mahatmasamatman and put the variable assignment into a document loaded listener.

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting for your content to load and be ready before executing any javascript. Put your code inside of

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // your code goes here
}, false);
```

Comment: do I need to add all of the functions? or just the variable? I just wrapped the variables in the event listener and it still doesn't work, i don't think that's the problem since the function only gets called once the dom is fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing the code in context, but I'd guess that the order of things your code means that `cart` doesn't have scope for some reason.

That said - you should avoid using global/globally scoped variables like this wherever possible and instead use message passing. Changing broadly scoped values like this is going to lead to bugs that are very hard to troubleshoot. Instead, I'd suggest passing a reference to `cart-wrapper` into the function to work with. Like so:

```js
function setcart(cart) {
    cart.style.display = "block";
}
```

EDIT: Also adding, as someone else pointed out, that you probably want to wrap that whole expression in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener

Comment: thanks for the answer i will try it out when i get a chance, btw i didn't change the variable only the style for it

Comment: I guess my overall point is that having some globally accessible "thing" then calling methods on it from various places can make it very hard later to try and figure out exactly which one of your call(s) to `cart.style.display` (if you have more than one) is actually making the change.